# ASP.NET: OnClientClick

Tags: asp.net

What's the point of the `OnClientClick` attribute for an ASP.NET control? Doesn't it simply generate an `onclick` attribute for the HTML element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does just generate the client-side onclick attribute.

It is there to distinguish it from OnClick attribute, which generates the server-side click event.

Answer (score 2):

yes

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick.asp

Answer (score 2):

OnClick property is used to set server side Click event. So OnClientClick property is used to set client side OnClick attribute.

```
<!-- Calls btn_Click server side click event -->
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" OnClick="btn_Click" />

<!-- Calls client side click event  -->
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" 
    OnClientClick="alert('client side click event.')" />
```